# Selecting kernel and hyperparameters for kernel PCA reduction

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm reading [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491962291)

I'm trying to optimize an unsupervised kernel PCA algorithm.
Here is some context:

> Another approach, this time entirely unsupervised, is to select the kernel and hyperparameters that yield
>   the lowest reconstruction error. However, reconstruction is not as easy as with linear PCA

....

> Fortunately, it is possible to find a point in the original space that
>   would map close to the reconstructed point. This is called the
>   reconstruction pre-image. Once you have this pre-image, you can
>   measure its squared distance to the original instance. You can then
>   select the kernel and hyperparameters that minimize this
>   reconstruction pre-image error.
>
> One solution is to train a supervised regression model, with the
>   projected instances as the training set and the original instances as
>   the targets.
>
> Now you can use grid search with cross-validation to find the kernel
>   and hyperparameters that minimize this pre-image reconstruction error.

The code provided in the book to perfom the reconstruction without cross validation is:

```
rbf_pca = KernelPCA(n_components = 2, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.0433,fit_inverse_transform=True)
X_reduced = rbf_pca.fit_transform(X)
X_preimage = rbf_pca.inverse_transform(X_reduced)

>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
>>> mean_squared_error(X, X_preimage)
32.786308795766132
```

My question is, how do i go about implementing cross validation to tune the kernel and hyperparameters to minimze the pre-image reconstruction error?

Here is my go at it so far:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA

mean_squared_error(X, X_preimage)

kpca=KernelPCA(fit_inverse_transform=True, n_jobs=-1) 

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = [{
        "kpca__gamma": np.linspace(0.03, 0.05, 10),
        "kpca__kernel": ["rbf", "sigmoid", "linear", "poly"]
    }]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv=3, scoring='mean_squared_error')
X_reduced = kpca.fit_transform(X)
X_preimage = kpca.inverse_transform(X_reduced)
grid_search.fit(X,X_preimage)
```

Thank you

Comment: Be advised that PCA and kPCA are completely different beasts.

Comment: You probably want to wrap a new estimator that would create a KErnelPCA for GSCV that would do all steps (fit, transform and then inverse_transform).

Comment: How would I go about that? I'm still a bit new to scikit learn. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` is capable of doing cross-validation of unsupervised learning (without a `y`) as can be seen [here in documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit):

> fit(X, y=None, groups=None, **fit_params)
>
> ```
> ...
> y : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_output], optional 
> Target relative to X for classification or regression; 
> None for unsupervised learning
> ...
> ```

So the only thing that needs to be handled is how the `scoring` will be done.

The following will happen in GridSearchCV:

1. The data `X` will be be divided into train-test splits based on folds defined in `cv` param
2. For each combination of parameters that you specified in `param_grid`, the model will be trained on the `train` part from the step above and then `scoring` will be used on `test` part.
3. The `scores` for each parameter combination will be combined for all the folds and averaged. Highest performing parameter combination will be selected.

Now the tricky part is 2. By default, if you provide a `'string'` in that, it will be converted to a `make_scorer` object internally. For `'mean_squared_error'` the relevant [code is here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c253b35a8f1a3827389fbee0f5bebcbc985/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L457):

```
....
neg_mean_squared_error_scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error,
                                        greater_is_better=False)
....
```

which is what you dont want, because that requires `y_true` and `y_pred`.

The other option is to make your [own custom scorer as discussed here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) with signature `(estimator, X, y)`. Something like below for your case:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
def my_scorer(estimator, X, y=None):
    X_reduced = estimator.transform(X)
    X_preimage = estimator.inverse_transform(X_reduced)
    return -1 * mean_squared_error(X, X_preimage)
```

Then use it in GridSearchCV like this:

```
param_grid = [{
        "gamma": np.linspace(0.03, 0.05, 10),
        "kernel": ["rbf", "sigmoid", "linear", "poly"]
    }]

kpca=KernelPCA(fit_inverse_transform=True, n_jobs=-1) 
grid_search = GridSearchCV(kpca, param_grid, cv=3, scoring=my_scorer)
grid_search.fit(X)
```

Comment: This is Brilliant! Thanks Vivek